# Switch Different Program Shortcut

Tags: windows-7, windows

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a shortcut or way in Windows 7 to switch same application’s windows, like Cmd + ~ in Mac.l](https://superuser.com/questions/435602/is-there-a-shortcut-or-way-in-windows-7-to-switch-same-applications-windows-li)

Is there any shortcut in windows switch windows in same program. In Mac OSX is

> Command + ~

Is there any shortcut like this in Windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Mac OSX, <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> switches between applications, even if you have multiple windows open in each application.  (You have three windows open in Firefox, but it still has only one item in the <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> popup.  This is what <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>~</kbd> is for.

In Windows, each window is represented as its own entity.  <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> cycles through all windows, of all applications.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on which application are you using, for example

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>

switches between tabs in all browsers in Windows. And take a look at the link below:

[keyboard Shorcuts](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-GB/windows7/Keyboard-shortcuts)

Comment: Incorrect.  This is usually to open a new tab.