# Linux Mint switch between windows of same application

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, linux-mint

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> circles through **all** the open windows.
But I'd like to reduce that choice to those windows of the application I'm currently in.

For instance, if I'm looking at a directory using Nemo, the file manager, and I want to jump to another directory that is open in another window, I don't want to cycle through all those other open applications, just the other open Nemo windows.

Is there a shortcut to do this?

I'm on Linux Mint Debian Edition and type on a German keyboard.

`uname -a` gives

```
Linux me 3.11-2-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.11.8-1 (2013-11-13) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Related (but for Windows): [Shortcut in Windows 7 to switch between same application’s windows, like Cmd + ` in OS X](https://superuser.com/q/435602/150988)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>^</kbd> does the trick.

I found this nowhere documented though and it's also not listed in `System Settings` -> `Keyboard` -> `Keyboard shortcuts`

Comment: Another approach is to use multiple desktops/workspaces.  Open  the applications you want to use together in the same desktop or move them there.

Answer (score 4):

On my Asus laptop, it's <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>~</kbd> (tilde), not caret.

Answer (score 0):

Found this while looking for the same shortcut on Fedora.
<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>~</kbd> works.