# What's the windows 10 equivalent of "Command `" on a mac

Tags: windows, shortcuts

For those who don't use a mac, command ` cycles between windows of the same application just like alt tab.

I was wondering if there is a windows 10 equivalent ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Shortcut in Windows 7 to switch between same application's windows, like Cmd + ` in OS X](http://superuser.com/q/435602/80304)

Answer (score 6):

There's no equivalent to <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> on Windows. You cannot cycle through open windows of an application if the application itself does not provide such functionality.

As mentioned in [another answer](https://superuser.com/a/1043935/80304), you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to cycle between tabs or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd> to cycle between open MDI windows.

Yet you can use <kbd>Windows</kbd>+*digit* where *digit* corresponds to the number of your application button on the Windows Taskbar.

For example, if Firefox has several open windows and its button is the fourth in the taskbar, then pressing <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd> will display the list of open Firefox windows. If you release the keys, you'll switch to the first Firefox window.

[image: Firefox windows in Windows taskbar]

Pressing <kbd>4</kbd> while still holding <kbd>Windows</kbd> key will highlight another window. (The window you're about to switch to will be displayed on the desktop and other open windows will be displayed as a “shadow”.) So press <kbd>4</kbd> until you see the required window, and then release both <kbd>4</kbd> and <kbd>Windows</kbd> to switch to it.

---

Alternatively, you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>: it will display the same window switcher as <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> but it won't disappear after you release the keys. Then you can use mouse or arrow keys to select the window you want to switch. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to confirm, or click it.

Actually, you can use arrow keys or mouse with the regular <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> switcher, just don't release the keys until you selected the required window.

Answer (score 3):

Well you could use CTRL + TAB when the window is in focus.
This will cycle through for example the tabs on Internet Explorer.

The key mapping for Windows keys to Mac keys is as follows:

```
Mac Key --> Windows Key
Control --> Ctrl 
Option  --> Alt 
Command (four leaf clover) --> Windows 
Delete  --> Backspace 
Return  --> Enter
```

But this does not mean that the shortcuts will work the same.
So the Mac's CMD (command) key iterates through all the same programs.
Windows CTRL + TAB will only iterate through tabs in the same program.

Info [found here](http://macs.about.com/od/faq1/f/windowskeyboard.htm).

Comment: I have many windows of the same application open. I want to quickly switch between them