# How to add number on apps

Tags: windows

So I know that is which number then use win+# to jump to that app.

[image: number on apps]

I want to see the numbers, I knew win+n. Just like Alt can show the numbers in the quick access tool bar for Word, Excel, Outlook, etc..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Shortcut in Windows 7 to switch between same application's windows, like Cmd + \` in OS X](https://superuser.com/questions/435602/shortcut-in-windows-7-to-switch-between-same-applications-windows-like-cmd)

Comment: Not sure the proposed duplicate is applicable. This question appears to be asking how to add a number that's visible in the UI.

Answer (score 1):

this works:

https://rammichael.com/7-taskbar-numberer

exactly what I wanted.